# Is there a method to find the values of an array from a collection in a separate collection in Firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have two collections `users` and `uploads`. The `user` collection shows details about the users that have registered to the app. It contains details about the user such as `name`, `userid` and `following` which is an array. The `following` array contains list of people that the user is following as shown here.

[image]

The `uploads` collection has the posts that are made by the users. Each document in the `uploads` collection has details such as the `postid`, `post` and `name` of the user who posted it as shown here.

[image]

I want to get only the uploads made by the users whom they are following.

For example, Sally follows three people Sam, Thomas and Ellie. I want Sally to get only the uploads that
are made by either of these three people from the `uploads` collection. Any help would be appreciated. Thank You

Answer (score 0):

I think [this](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#array_membership) might be what you're looking for. You could fetch the users' `following` array and then use that array to fetch uploads containing people from the `following`. As a sidenote I'd recommend the userId instead of the name of the user as these might not be unique.

Comment: Would this work if the `following` array contains more than 10 users?

Comment: In that case you could do the query in batches of 10 users.